# Correct way to use $http and $q within Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I need to do a reverse geo coding and get the name of the city from the latitude/longitude information.

I have created an Angular service which makes a call to the Google maps api via $http. From the returned data I only need the name of the city. I was struggling with the async nature of $http within the Angular service. The only way I could get it to run was to create my own promise with $q in the service.

It works but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Any feedback is more than welcome!

```
var app = angular.module('devApp', []);

app.factory('reverseGeoCoder', function($http, $q) {
    var service = {
        getAddress: function(lat, lng) {
            var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' +lng;
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
                // extract the address and return it to the caller
                deferred.resolve(data.data.results[0].formatted_address);
            }, function(reason) {
                deferred.reject(reason);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
    return service;
});

app.controller('mainController', function(reverseGeoCoder) {
    var vm = this;
    reverseGeoCoder.getAddress(47.353166, 8.558387).then(function(data) {
            vm.address = data;
        }, function(reason) {
            console.log('reverse geocoding failed, reason: ' + reason);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$http` itself already returns a promise, so you don't have to return your own:

```
app.factory('reverseGeoCoder', function($http, $q) {
    var service = {
        getAddress: function(lat, lng) {
            var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' + lat + ',' +lng;

            return $http.get(url).then(function(data) {
                // extract the address and return it to the caller
                return data.data.results[0].formatted_address;
            }, function(reason) {
                return reason;
            });
        }
    };
    return service;
});
```

As long as you keep returning promises you can chain them with a `.then`, once you return a non-promise value it will be resolved/rejected.